# annoying banner on webpage from dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver-templates

I used Dreamweaver to create a website off a template i got from timothy framework, the website can be seen here  http://www.manchestertemplate.info/ If you notice at very top of the webpage there is a thin orange strip or banner that is not part of the background image. it looks fine on that website, but if your trying to change the wallpaper it might not look as good.I really want to get rid of it and i cant seem to find the code for it anywhere, would it be in the HTML or the css style sheets. Please help.

Comment: It was easy enough to just remove the "....if" and view the issue on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with the id of "wrapper" has a border-top of "10px #BF6000 solid". This is your culprit.

A good way to quickly troubleshoot these sorts of issues is with Google chrome's "Inspect Element" feature (or Firefox's equivalent). It's quite powerful and will save you a great deal of time.

Comment: You should consider it's use all the time, or Firefox's equivalent. It will save you a great deal of time and allow you to quickly find the settings you want when tweaking styles.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CSS` file, there is a border on the `#wrapper` element:

```
border-top:10px #BF6000 solid;
```

Delete that and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `styles.css` file and look for the `#wrapper` element.

In order to remove the annoying banner, remove the following rule:
`border-top:10px #BF6000 solid;`

If you want to still have the main section of the page pushed down a little from the top so that you can see the background, change the following rule within the same element: `margin:0 auto;` to: `margin:10px auto 0 auto;`

This change will push the #wrapper element down 10 pixels from the top of the page, so it will look exactly like how it does now, but the banner will change appropriately when you alter the background.